# How to collect data from redis with fluentd or maybe how to develop my plugin in fluentd

Tags: fluentd

Fluentd collected data from nginx log file before.
Now I have put nginx access_log into redis with my new module.
I want to collect data from redis with fluentd and send the data to a fluentd server.
So how to collect data from redis?
Some one ever do this?

Comment: How do you intend to read data from Redis? ASAIK, currently there is no plugin that systematically gets data out of Redis, but I am curious to know what your use case is.

Comment: I have implemented the plugin what I want.now my nginx's access_logs were written into redis,and fluentd get the log contents from redis.It worked well.